# Accessing dictionary contents after creating dictionary using a loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm doing an exercise of counting words in a string. I used a loop to count the words and insert them in a dictionary.  I then tried to access the dictionary contents but the dictionary is empty.  When I call the key to get the value, I get an keyerror that it doesn't exist.  What am I missing here?

```
    sample_text = 'Fabrication of Metallic Pressure Vessels delivers comprehensive coverage of the various processes used in the fabrication of process equipment. The authors, both accomplished engineers, offer readers a broad understanding of the steps and processes required to fabricate pressure vessels, including cutting, forming, welding, machining, and testing, as well as suggestions on controlling costs.'
punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''


def CountingDict(text):
    new_dict = {}
    ele = text.lower()
    new_string = ''
    
    for l in ele:
        if l not in punc:
            new_string += l
        else:
            new_string = new_string.replace(l,"")
    
    new_string = new_string.split()

    for word in new_string:
        if word in new_dict:
            new_dict[word] += 1
        else:
            new_dict[word] = 1
    return new_dict


CountingDict(sample_text)
print(new_dict['required'])
```

Comment: You are missing the assignment. Change `CountingDict(sample_text)` to `new_dict = CountingDict(sample_text)`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the amount of words you could use the `split` function that comes with Python. It will return a list and you can get the length of that list using `len`.

```
string = "some large string"

len(string.split(" ")) ## Note the space
```

Should return 3.